# How do I remove all files in a folder except just some specified files?

Tags: command-line, files, rm

I want to remove all files in a directory while leaving just some specified files, they don't have anything in common by name. How could I achieve that?

For example, the file names I want to keep are:

`file_1.png`, `another_file.jpg`, `some_music.mp3`

Answer (score 21):

If you are using bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -- !(file1|file2|file3)
```

The first line just activates extended pattern matching, and after that we use one of them:

> `!(pattern-list)` matches anything except one of the given patterns

and the pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a `|`.

---

Or with `zsh`

```
setopt extendedglob
rm -- ^(file1|file2)
```

---

Or, more  portable, using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'file1' ! -name 'file2' -type f -exec rm -v {} +
```

Comment: It might be useful to include how to return the optional shell behaviour back (`shopt -u extglob`).

Comment: Is it possible to supply a filename of file containing list of files that need to be kept? E.g. `!(<file>)`.

Answer (score 8):

Make a subdirectory `tmp`, move all all the files that you want to keep to that directory and do a `rm -f *` afterwards. That will not affect the `tmp` directory.

After that just do:

```
mv tmp/* .
rmdir tmp
```

(Assuming none of the files you moved starts with a dot).

This is one of the few cases where it makes sense to use the mouse and a file browser like Nautilus where you can actually can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the few files you want to keep and then use the menu: `Edit -> Invert Selection` to get the other files and then delete those.

Comment: the moving files to tmp directory sounds nice. Anyway, I have to do this with command line. Thanks!

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo The tmp has the advantage that it first seperates the files into two sets, before irrevocably removing the ones you don't want. So you can run an `ls` to see if you didn't miss any of the files you want to preserve.

Answer (score 3):

Add the names of the files you want to keep to a text file, one per line. This file should not be in the directory or you should add its name too.

If the name of your directory is *foo* and the name of the file is *bar*, do the following.

```
find foo -type f -print0|grep -vzZ -f bar|xargs -0 rm
```

This does the following:

1. `find -type f` searches for the names of all files in *foo* and its subdirectories and prints them to STDOUT. With option `-print0` it delimits the filenames with NUL bytes.
2. `grep -v -f bar` excludes all filenames that match a line in *bar*. With option `-z` it treats its input as a set of lines delimited by NUL byte, with option `-Z` it delimts its output with a NUL byte.
3. `xargs rm` calls `rm` repeatedly to delete the files. With option `-0` it treats its input as a set of lines delimited by NUL byte.

This works with filenames containing white space.

Comment: This won't work as filenames can have newlines in them.

Comment: @Anthon changed the options of find, grep, xargs to cope with filenames containing whitespace, including newline

Comment: If you want to use `find` I would rather do `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'file1' ! -name 'file2' -type f -exec rm -vi {} +`